# Shell script help for reading in file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have an assignment where I am reading in a file, here is my code

```
#Reads in file
while read line; do
echo `wc -l` "is the number of students in the input file."
echo `grep '^[^4]'| wc -l`

done <students.txt
```

Essentially I am trying to display the number of student ID's that do not start with a 4. I was hoping grep '^[^4]'| wc -l would do the trick but it just returns 0. Below is the text that is being read in. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this (this is an intro UNIX class so I can't really use anything over the top right now haha).

```
256-56-8411  Bob      3.61  junior     cs
471-44-7458  Tim      3.45  senior     ce
326-56-4286  Rajesh   2.97  freshman   te
548-66-1124  Eric     2.88  sophomore  ee
447-21-3599  John     2.51  junior     cs
911-41-1256  Rebecca  3.92  senior     cs
854-22-6372  Robin    2.45  freshman   te
```

Comment: Does the immediate command `grep '^[^4]'` on your input file show any good result?

Comment: No it doesn't display anything. =/. This is a shell script also, so it shouldn't show anything from just that command right?

Comment: Don't use a while loop. Specify the filename for each command, e.g. ``echo `grep '^[^4]' students.txt | wc -l` ``

Comment: That's exactly why I asked you to try *as a separate command*. If that particular grep doesn't find anything to begin with, your entire script (and subsequent debugging thereof) is worthless. Hold on, I'm going to run some tests.

Comment: @that other guy, Yeah I see why it wasn't good to use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it mandatory to use `read`? Because you don't have to. What do you think about a simple `grep` or `wc -l`?

```
FILE="students.txt"

echo "$(cat "$FILE" | wc -l) is the number of students in the input file"
echo "$(grep -c '^[^4]' "$FILE") is the number of student ID's that do not start with a 4"
```

Comment: That worked, yeah it isn't requirement to use read. I'll read up on what exactly you did since i'm kinda confused on how that worked haha! Thanks my man!

Comment: @that other guy: Just out of curiosity, why do you prefer the double quotes even when they're not necessary? For example when declaring the `$FILE` variable.

Comment: @wadeaston: Glad this helped. The `$(command)` contruct is similar to what the backticks do: evaluate the expression inside before evaluating the whole, containing expression. `grep -c` is just a shortcut for `grep | wc -l`. Whenever you are in doubt regarding the use of some parameter, use `man command`.

Comment: @FlaviusAnton I don't feel strongly about it, but since newbies copy this code the rule "prefer quoting filenames" is easier and more consistent than "prefering quoting filenames, except in assignments, unless it's in an embedded $(), or if it has glob characters, but only if it assigns an array". Plus, it makes SO syntax highlighting prettier.

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. Use `$(wc -l < "$FILE")`.